# How to make game objects follow a path in order in Unity along a bezier curve

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bezier

I have a single Object moving along a Bezier Curve but i have multiple objects that need to follow this path in order but they all follow at the same time.The object is a snake type enemy in a space shooter game.

I have so far tried to make all objects children but in doing this they remain in a straight line to the parent when follow the Bezier Curve.
I have also made all objects separate and attached the Bezier Script to these so they all follow the same route and this works but only they follow the same path at the same time.

```
public class BezierFollow : MonoBehaviour{

[SerializeField]
private Transform[] routes;

private int routeToGo;

private float tParam;

private Vector2 enemyPosition;

[SerializeField]
public float speedModifier = 0.5f;

private bool coroutineAloud;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    routeToGo = 0;
    tParam = 0f;
    //speedModifier = 0.5f;
    coroutineAloud = true;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (coroutineAloud)
    {
        StartCoroutine(GoByTheRouteRoutine(routeToGo));
    }
}

private IEnumerator GoByTheRouteRoutine(int routeNumber)
{
    coroutineAloud = false;

    Vector2 p0 = routes[routeNumber].GetChild(0).position;
    Vector2 p1 = routes[routeNumber].GetChild(1).position;
    Vector2 p2 = routes[routeNumber].GetChild(2).position;
    Vector2 p3 = routes[routeNumber].GetChild(3).position;

    while(tParam < 1)
    {
        tParam += Time.deltaTime * speedModifier;

        enemyPosition = Mathf.Pow(1 - tParam, 3) * p0 +
            3 * Mathf.Pow(1 - tParam, 2) * tParam * p1 +
            3 * (1 - tParam) * Mathf.Pow(tParam, 2) * p2 +
            Mathf.Pow(tParam, 3) * p3;

        transform.position = enemyPosition;
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

    tParam = 0f;

    routeToGo += 1;

    if(routeToGo > routes.Length - 1)
        routeToGo = 0;

    coroutineAloud = true;

}}
```

Here is the routes script i don't think you will need but will include this

```
public class Route : MonoBehaviour{
[SerializeField]
private Transform[] controlPoints;

private Vector2 gizmosPos;

private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    for(float t = 0; t <= 1; t += 0.05f)
    {
        gizmosPos = Mathf.Pow(1 - t, 3) * controlPoints[0].position +
            3 * Mathf.Pow(1 - t, 2) * t * controlPoints[1].position +
            3 * (1 - t) * Mathf.Pow(t, 2) * controlPoints[2].position +
            Mathf.Pow(t, 3) * controlPoints[3].position;

        Gizmos.DrawSphere(gizmosPos, 0.25f);
    }

    Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector2(controlPoints[0].position.x, controlPoints[0].position.y),
        new Vector2(controlPoints[1].position.x, controlPoints[1].position.y));

    Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector2(controlPoints[2].position.x, controlPoints[2].position.y),
       new Vector2(controlPoints[3].position.x, controlPoints[3].position.y));
}}
```

I think what i need to do is have each object not be a child object and all have the script attached to follow the route but also have a delayed time before it follows along the path but not sure how to go about this. I was thinking this might need to be done in a separate script because in the bezier curve script it is set so the object starts again at the beginning of the route once reaches the end

Comment: Does https://answers.unity.com/questions/894796/how-to-make-object-follow-path.html not help? Or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKWTpi70a_E? (mute it because the music is literally the worst)

Comment: Hi, no unfortunately they do not cover what it is im trying to implement,i have actually seen those links, i already have the functionality with one object following a bezier curve, i am needing multiple objects follow the same curve

Comment: If I'm reading your code correctly, isn't every follower defined to use exactly the same values? E.g. if you build 10 of them, all 10 will move identically because they all start moving at the same time (I don't see a random X frame delay that you take into account in `update()`) and they all travel at the same speed (I don't see a randomization for that in `start()`).

Comment: yes that is correct, this why i am asking for help to have objects follow the path in order

Comment: @DavidMarsh Could you perhaps provide an example video of the current problem, I don't seem to understand the exact behavior you want to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: But then I'm confused, @DavidMarsh - describing those two things should be enough to _add_ those two things, no? Add a `framedelay` property (instance, not static) that you set to a random value in `start()` and then in `update()` you start with "is this value 0? if not, decrement and return, if so, actually run the rest of the code"? That gives you the "different delays for each follower", and then if you make `start` randomize the speed factors, too, now you have followers at different speeds, starting at different times?

Comment: @Hristo unable to get a video up as away from computer, to give you an idea of what im after, think of the enemy ships in the classic galaga game that fly down in formation one after the other, thats what im aiming for

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i did try something similar with a seperate script on each object using invoke then a time delay but wasn't working correctly, its the same speeds i want but to all follow in formation

Comment: Then we run into part of [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask): if you already tried something, please show what you tried (e.g. add an extra block of code prefaced with something along the lines of "I tried the following, but the result was X and I expected Y") because that is important information for people to see. Maybe you simply missed a keyword and your code was already 99% of the way there.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yeah, I personally would like to see an example of some code (attempt) or a video/gif showing the problem. Or OP can extend his question with a deeper description of the problem and what he wants to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Know what you are trying to achieve and i do believe you can do this with an extra script without changing your current code.

Here i have made a new script called EnemyBehavior.

```
public class EnemyBehavior : MonoBehaviour{
public Path pathToFollow;

//PATH INFO
public int currentWayPointID = 0;

//speeds
public float speed = 2;
public float reachDistance = 0.4f;
public float rotationSpeed = 5f;

float distance; //DISTANCE TO NEXT PATH POINT

public bool useBezier = false;

//STATE MACHINES
public enum EnemyStates
{
    ON_PATH,        
    IDLE
}
public EnemyStates enemyState;

public int enemyID;

void Update()
{
    switch (enemyState)
    {
        case EnemyStates.ON_PATH:
            MoveOnThePath(pathToFollow);
            break;            
        case EnemyStates.IDLE:

            break;
    }
}

void MoveToFormation()
{
    //transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, formation.gridList[enemyID], speed * Time.deltaTime);
    //if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, formation.gridList[enemyID])<= 0.001f)
    {
        //transform.SetParent(formation.gameObject.transform);
        transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
        enemyState = EnemyStates.IDLE;
    }
}

void MoveOnThePath(Path path)
{
    if (useBezier)
    {
        //MOVING THE ENEMY
        distance = Vector3.Distance(path.bezierObjList[currentWayPointID], transform.position);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, path.bezierObjList[currentWayPointID], speed * Time.deltaTime);
        //ROTATION OF YOUR ENEMY
        var direction = path.bezierObjList[currentWayPointID] - transform.position;

        if (direction != Vector3.zero)
        {
            direction.z = 0;
            direction = direction.normalized;
            var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        distance = Vector3.Distance(path.pathObjList[currentWayPointID].position, transform.position);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, path.pathObjList[currentWayPointID].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        //ROTATION OF ENEMY
        var direction = path.pathObjList[currentWayPointID].position - transform.position;

        if (direction != Vector3.zero)
        {
            direction.y = 0;
            direction = direction.normalized;
            var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }        
}}
```

Attach this script to all the game objects that you intend to use the path and don't forget to assign the path on these in the inspector.

You may need to adjust the direction to suit your needs if it is a 2D game but this should work for you.
Let me know how you get on and feel free to direct contact me.

Comment: Brilliant, works great after changing the direction to direction.x, all objects following along nicely i cannot thank you enough for helping, very kind

Comment: Welcome glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach:

1. Attach *BezierCurve* to all gameObject that need the behaviour. Don't keep any Parent-Child relationship.
2. Prevent *BezierCurve* to follow/start automatically. Keep a bool to stop, in case you need.
3. Create a new script *BezierCurveBatch*, attach to main(Parent) gameObject and have *List<BezierCurve>* contains reference of children. In same script, keep a *float*, let's say *delayStartCurve* to manage time between two *BezierCurve* start.
4. In BezierCurveBatch, start the BezierCurve from *List<BezierCurve> children* after every *delayStartCurve*.

I have provided a demo script code. Not tested but it should work.

```
public class BezierCurve
{
    //Starts following bezier curve.
    public void StartFollow()
    {
        //some code here.
    }
}

public class BezierCurveBatch : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    List<BezierCurve> m_lstChildren;

    [SerializeField]
    float m_delayStartCurve = 10;
    float m_timeLeftToStartNextChild = 0;

    bool m_isRunBatchCurve = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Start batch follow after each interval.
    /// </summary>
    public void StartBatch()
    {
        m_isRunBatchCurve = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!m_isRunBatchCurve)
            return;

        m_timeLeftToStartNextChild -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (m_timeLeftToStartNextChild <= 0.0f)
        {
            if (m_lstChildren.Count > 0) //if we have children left.
            {
                BezierCurve l_bCurveToStart = m_lstChildren[0];     //Getting top object.
                m_lstChildren.RemoveAt(0);                          //removing top object.
                l_bCurveToStart.StartFollow();                      //Start follow bezier curve
                m_timeLeftToStartNextChild = m_delayStartCurve;     //resetting time.
            }

            if (m_lstChildren.Count == 0)       //After processing last object, check if need to continue for next object.
                m_isRunBatchCurve = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will try this now and report back, appreciate the help

Comment: Hi, struggling to implement this, do you have an example? also number 1. don't keep any parent child relationship but number 3 you say to attach to parent object?

Comment: @DavidMarsh I have updated my answer with sample code.

Comment: The list and variables in the BezierCurveBatch do not seem to be showing when attached to parent object, even though they are serialised, only warning i see in console is...'BezierCurveBatch.m_lstChildren' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

Comment: @DavidMarsh. Its because i didn't know whether your *BezierCurve* class is derived from *Monobehaviour* or not.

* If your *BezierCurve* is derived from *Monobehaviour*, then it was already serializing in editor and you just need to drag and drop the references in List.
* If your *BezierCurve* is not derived from *Monobehaviour*, then add *[System.Serializable]* attribute on your class *BezierCurve*.

Again my sample code was just for logic reference.

Comment: Ah i see, its BezierFollow the class now, i will change this

Comment: the BezierFollow does derive from Monobehaviour so should i have the first class you added at top of your code also derive from monobehaviour?

Comment: also the StartFollow in the first class i am unsure off or why we have the second class at top of the BezierCurveBatch

Comment: i see why we use it now, but don't think there should be a class placed there when i already have the BezierFollow script with the code

Comment: I think this is an incorrect way to do this, even when get the List to show in the inspector it cannot be populated with Game Objects,also why would the list be a list of a the class BezierCurve? all curves are already set in the main script, it should be a List of Game Objects and not a list with another class name as you have made in your code, maybe why the List can't be populated i guess. thank you for trying though i appreciate it and will try on Unity Forums